# Gitlab: when merged to master branch hooks required for deployment

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket

When a branch is merged to master branch on basis of a pull request the hook should execute a command in the deployment server to pull all the latest changes from the git repository.

How to add this hook where the pull request is merged to master?

How the developers developing to push directly to master branch?